# Repeat the alphabet

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, logic

Im a beginner programmer and I know that this is probably an easy problem, Im having difficulty understanding the logic.
Im working on a program that deciphers Caesars Cipher with ROT13 cipher. Its one of the tasks at FreeCodeCamp. But their solutions are quite hard for me to understand at my skill level, so I want to make it my own way. I managed to get it quite far but i stumbled upon a problem. Im working with arrays, and I will return the array with deciphered message. The output in this case should be [F, R, E, E, , C, O, D, E, , C, A, M, P], but instead I get [undefined, "R", undefined, undefined, undefined, "O", undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, "P"]. I understand that I get undefined because j+13 is bigger than 26 in cases of undefined and there are only 26 letters in alphabet or in array. I cant figure out how to make, so that alphabet will repeat itself in the cases where j+13 > 26. Any tips would be really helpful

```
let str = "SERR PBQR PNZC";
        let strArr = str.split("");
        let alphabet = [];
        let tempArr = [];
        for (i = 65; i <= 90; i++){
            alphabet.push(String.fromCharCode(i))
        }
        for (i = 0; i < strArr.length; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < alphabet.length; j++) {
                if (strArr[i] === alphabet[j]) {
                    tempArr.push(alphabet[j+13]);

                }

            }

        }
    console.log(tempArr);
```

Comment: A variable that has been declared without a `var` keyword is a global. Globals can be accessed by everything. `i` is global

Comment: Just wanted to say, this is how an ideal StackOverflow question is supposed to look.  You attempted to solve it on your own, described the problem very clearly, provided your code and sample data... Good job!

Comment: @geoorg thank you! Its really nice to hear that.The whole policy on posting on StackOverflow seems intimidating for a beginner who is stuck on simple problems. Im glad that I did it the right way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`alphabet[j+13]` is often undefined since `j+13` is past the end of the alphabet whenever `j >= 13`. You can use the [remainder operator %](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder) to effectively wrap around to the beginning of the array again instead of going past the end of it. Just change it to `alphabet[(j+13)%26]`:

```js
let str = "SERR PBQR PNZC";
        let strArr = str.split("");
        let alphabet = [];
        let tempArr = [];
        for (i = 65; i <= 90; i++){
            alphabet.push(String.fromCharCode(i))
        }
        for (i = 0; i < strArr.length; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < alphabet.length; j++) {
                if (strArr[i] === alphabet[j]) {
                    tempArr.push(alphabet[(j+13)%26]);

                }

            }

        }
    console.log(tempArr);
```

Comment: This works. But I still dont understand why. Can you please explain what we just did with that %26? Also, I would like to include spaces in my array. It seems they are deleted with my code.

Comment: @Urrby This is an exercise for you so I wanted to make minimal changes to your code and don't want to just give away the solution for spaces. I will give you a hint though, use an if statement to detect if the current char is a space and if it is then push a space onto `tempArr`.

Comment: `%26` just takes the remainder of division by 26. Suppose `j = 20`. Then `j + 13` is `33` which is past the end of the alphabet array, so you get undefined, but `33 % 26` is `7` so you've effectively wrapped around back to the beginning of the alphabet instead of going past the end where everything is `undefined`.

Comment: I did that, before reading your comment and it works. But for some reason i get the output with more then 1 space. After your change I wrote this:
if (strArr[i] === " ") {tempArr.push(" ");}.
And thank you for explanation on %26. I understand it now.

Comment: I'd use `% alphabet.length` instead of the magic number `%26`.

Comment: @Urrby That's happening because you loop through the whole alphabet for each character in the string and you're doing that inside the loop, so you're adding 26 spaces each time, one for each character of the alphabet. Make sure you add the space outside your `for (j = 0;` loop through the alphabet.

Comment: @Paulpro but isnt looking for each character the point? The way I see it, I look each individual character and if they are the same, they get pushed into tempArr. If the current charracter is space, space is pushed in tempArr. I dont understand why it would push 26 spaces...

Comment: @Urrby Space isn't part of `alphabet`, so you know the test `strArr[i] === alphabet[j]` is never true for a space. That's why you were missing spaces before, the test was never true so you didn't push anything for spaces.

Comment: @Urrby When you add `if (strArr[i] === " ") {tempArr.push(" ");}` inside the inner loop then you add a space on every iteration of the inner loop because `strArr[i] === " "` is true regardless of what `j` is. That's why you want to do the test outside the `for (j = 0;` loop instead.

Comment: @Paulpro how can it be true regardless of j? And how does space adds to every iteration If never declared it. The way Im seeing it is that im just looking through if space happens to be there, and not declaring that it should.

Comment: @Urrby How could `strArr[i] === " "` depend on `j`? There is no `j` in that expression. If it's true, it's true no matter what `j` is. If it's false, it's false no matter what `j` is. If it's true then it's true on all 26 iterations of `for (j = 0; j < alphabet.length; j++) {`

Comment: @Paulpro Oh my god, I see it now. Ive been overthinking so much that I got everything mixed up. Thank you for your help. Really appriciate it, taking the time, to helping me with stupid questions. Thank you again

Comment: No problem, @Urrby , glad I could help.